# Returning jagged array of objects as IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>>

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ienumerable

I'm working on an ASP.NET API and I'm having some issuses retrieving a jagged array of different derived object from a base class.
So I have this Base class:

```
public class BaseContract
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public enum ContractTypes
    {
        A,
        B           
    }
    public ContractTypes contractType;
    public string provider { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
    public enum OfficeLocations 
    { 
        A,
        B,
        C
    }
    public OfficeLocations office_location;
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime finishDate { get; set; }
}
```

And then 4 more classes deriving from this:

```
public class class1 : BaseContract
{
    public enum ProductTypes { 
        A,
        B,
        C
    }
    public ProductTypes productType;
}
```

And like that i have 4 classes.

Before going into getting the data from the DB i'm filling the classes with some random data manually:

```
public class ContractsController : ApiController
{

    BaseContract[][] contracts = new BaseContract[][]{
    new class1[] 
    {
        new class1 {
            ID=12412341, 
            contractType = BaseContract.ContractTypes.A,
            productType= Protection_automobile.ProductTypes.B, 
            startDate= new DateTime(2014, 3, 15),
            finishDate= new DateTime(2014, 4, 11),
            office_location=BaseContract.OfficeLocations.A,
            provider="abc"},
        new class1 {
            ID=52412341, 
            contractType = BaseContract.ContractTypes.B,
            productType= Protection_automobile.ProductTypes.C, 
            startDate= new DateTime(2015, 7, 24),
            finishDate= new DateTime(2015, 9, 2),
            office_location=BaseContract.OfficeLocations.C,
            provider="wer"}

    },
    new class2[]
    {
        new class2{
            ID=22374341,
            contractType= BaseContract.ContractTypes.A,
            productType = Protection_biens.ProductTypes.B,
            startDate = new DateTime(2015,2,2),
            finishDate =new DateTime(2015,4,17),
            office_location = BaseContract.OfficeLocations.B,
            provider= "wer"
        },
        new class2{
            ID=12374659,
            contractType = BaseContract.ContractTypes.A,
            productType = Protection_biens.ProductTypes.A,
            startDate = new DateTime(2015,7,1),
            finishDate = new DateTime(2015, 5,30),
            office_location = BaseContract.OfficeLocations.A,
            provider = "abc"                                    
        },
        new class2{
             ID=12374659,
            contractType = BaseContract.ContractTypes.B,
            productType = Protection_biens.ProductTypes.A,
            startDate = new DateTime(2015,8,2),
            finishDate = new DateTime(2015, 5,30),
            office_location = BaseContract.OfficeLocations.C,
            provider = "abc"
        }
    },
    new class3[]
    {
        new class3{
            ID=32378659,
            contractType = BaseContract.ContractTypes.A,
            productType = Responsabilite_civile.ProductTypes.A,
            startDate = new DateTime(2014,8,2),
            finishDate = new DateTime(2015, 1,8),
            office_location = BaseContract.OfficeLocations.A,
            provider = "abc"
        },
        new class3{
            ID=42395634,
            contractType = BaseContract.ContractTypes.A,
            productType = Responsabilite_civile.ProductTypes.B,
            startDate = new DateTime(2015,7,16),
            finishDate = new DateTime(2015, 8,8),
            office_location = BaseContract.OfficeLocations.B,
            provider = "wer"
        },
        new class3{
             ID=42305635,
            contractType = BaseContract.ContractTypes.A,
            productType = Responsabilite_civile.ProductTypes.A,
            startDate = new DateTime(2015,9,29),
            finishDate = new DateTime(2015, 10,6),
            office_location = BaseContract.OfficeLocations.B,
            provider = "abc"
        },
    },
    new class4[]
    {
        new class4{
             ID=14385634,
            contractType = BaseContract.ContractTypes.B,
            productType = Protection_persones.ProductTypes.B,
            startDate = new DateTime(2015,8,4),
            finishDate = new DateTime(2015, 8,9),
            office_location = BaseContract.OfficeLocations.A,
            provider = "wer"
        },
        new class4{
             ID=14385635,
            contractType = BaseContract.ContractTypes.B,
            productType = Protection_persones.ProductTypes.B,
            startDate = new DateTime(2015,9,11),
            finishDate = new DateTime(2015, 9,27),
            office_location = BaseContract.OfficeLocations.A,
            provider = "abc"
        }

    }





    };

    class1[] pContracts = new class1[]{

        new class1{
             ID=14385634,
            contractType = BaseContract.ContractTypes.A,
            productType = Protection_persones.ProductTypes.B,
            startDate = new DateTime(2015,8,4),
            finishDate = new DateTime(2015, 8,9),
            office_location = BaseContract.OfficeLocations.A,
            provider = "wer"
        },
        new class1{
             ID=14385635,
            contractType = BaseContract.ContractTypes.B,
            productType = Protection_persones.ProductTypes.A,
            startDate = new DateTime(2015,9,11),
            finishDate = new DateTime(2015, 9,27),
            office_location = BaseContract.OfficeLocations.A,
            provider = "abc"
        }
    };
```

As you can see, I have a jagged array, and then a simple array.
When i try to get the simple array data as `IEnumerable<class1>` it works.
But when i try to get the jagged array as `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<BaseContract>>` it throws an error .

```
    public IEnumerable<class1> GetAllContracts()
    {
        return pContracts;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<BaseContract>> getcontracts(){
        return contracts;
    }
```

Should I change my jagged array data structure? Or what is the correct wat to retrieve that jagged array?

Thank you.

Comment: And what error? The code you posted works perfectly.

Comment: for real? When i call  `http://localhost:49269/api/contracts` i get an ExceptionType error. And when i call `http://localhost:49269/api/pContracts` i get my json correctly.

Comment: Then it's a problem of the serializer. Sorry, I can't help you with that. The C# side is just fine.